# AdMob implement (only code, no main storyboard)

Tags: swift, admob

I want put Ad banner in my app.
I don't have the storyboard, I 've 4 ViewCOntroller, in the main I've this, can someone help me please?

In AppDelegate: `GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "...")`

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var window: UIWindow?

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title="Andrea Damante Quiz"
        self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "andrea15.jpeg")!)

        let backgroundImage = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        backgroundImage.image = UIImage(named: "andrea15.jpeg")
        backgroundImage.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        self.view.insertSubview(backgroundImage, at: 0)
        setupViews()
    }

    @objc func btnGetStartedAction() {
        let v=QuizVC()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(v, animated: true)
    }

    func setupViews() {
        self.view.addSubview(lblTitle)
        lblTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 150).isActive=true
        lblTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
        lblTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive=true
        lblTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive=true

        self.view.addSubview(btnGetStarted)
        btnGetStarted.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive=true
        btnGetStarted.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive=true
        btnGetStarted.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive=true
        btnGetStarted.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true
    }

    let lblTitle: UILabel = {
        let lbl=UILabel()
        lbl.text="Quiz"
        lbl.textColor=UIColor.darkGray
        lbl.textAlignment = .center
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 46)
        lbl.numberOfLines=2
        lbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        return lbl
    }()

    let btnGetStarted: UIButton = {
        let btn=UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Via!", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor=UIColor.orange
        btn.layer.cornerRadius=5
        btn.layer.masksToBounds=true
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnGetStartedAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()
}
```

Comment: import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
    
    
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

Comment: Please edit your question to make it on-topic as explained in the help page: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._

Comment: upload logs in your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare and set up a `GADBannerView` and add it to your view controller. You won't need a `UIWindow`. Use this code:

```
import GoogleMobileAds
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

        addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
    }

    func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        view.addConstraints(
            [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .bottom,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                                attribute: .top,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0),
             NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0)
            ])
    }

}
```

which was taken from here: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner.

Also make sure to set the ad unit ID and the delegate:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        ...

    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
}
```

But again, you'll everything you need in the [official guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner).

Comment: not works... should I to create a view controller with only this code ? or add at my VC ?

Comment: addBannerViewToView(bannerView) // this code give me error

Comment: https://gyazo.com/10e2d98a6e2bb40aaa0ee89ebe9c7b03 
Up . don't work look

Comment: Cesare se mi aggiungi su Skype, mi dai una mano al volo ! https://join.skype.com/invite/dg2OjzGm6caq

Comment: devi aggiungere la funzione al tuo view controller esistente. L'errore ti dice che hai 2 view controller con lo stesso nome.

Comment: Finalmente ci sono riuscito, ora via col video AD :(

Comment: vorrei metterlo appesa si apre l'app e basta

Comment: basta che segui il tutorial: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/rewarded-video